# 'int' object is not subscriptable - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am currently making a password manager that includes a password generator. My thought prosses is that for each character of the given password length the program would randomly take a variable from the "chars" list and then take a random index of the string and add it to the final "password string.

```
letters_small = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
letters_cap = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
nums = "134567890"
special_chars = "!@#$%^&*?><"

chars = [letters_cap, letters_small, nums, special_chars]

Charlist = []

password = ""
len = ""

def generator():
    while True:
        len = input("Enter the length of the password: ")
        break
        for i in range(len):
            Charlist = chars[random.randint(0, 3)]
            password.append(Charlist[0[random.randint(0, len(Charlist[0]))]])
```

Everytime I try and debug this section it raises this error

```
 SyntaxWarning: 'int' object is not subscriptable; perhaps you missed a comma?
 password.append(Charlist[0[random.randint(0, len(Charlis))]])
```

I tried to fix it by adding an index in the last line, but that didn't do anything

```
password.append(Charlist[0[random.randint(0, len(Charlis[0]))]])
```

Comment: password is a string, you cannot use append for string datatype

Comment: `...[0[rando...`. You're missing a closing `]` for the expression `Charlist[0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because `[0[...]]`. Here, 0 is an integer, not a `list`, so, it is not subscriptable. Also, there are many other problems too. like `len` is a reserved word. When you use it as a variable and try to `len(Charlist[0])`, it gives error. `len` is an `str` when input is taken in it.

Moreover, the `break` statement and `while` loops are unnecessary.

---

### Corrected Code

```
import random

letters_small = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
letters_cap = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
nums = "134567890"
special_chars = "!@#$%^&*?><"

chars = [letters_cap, letters_small, nums, special_chars]

Charlist = []

password = ""
passwordLen = ""


def generator():
    passwordLen = input("Enter the length of the password: ")
    passwordLen = int(passwordLen)

    password = ""
    for i in range(passwordLen):
        Charlist = chars[random.randint(0, 3)]
        password += Charlist[random.randint(0, len(Charlist)-1)]

    print(password)


generator()
```

Comment: So if that 0 was refering to the list, this issue wouldn't have existed? ( apart from that poorly named variable)

Comment: yes. Here CharList is `str`, so don't need to do `CharList[0][..]`, Moreover, some other issues, like `len`, and type conversion also need to be corrected.

Comment: `len` is not reserved (or else the assignment itself would raise an error); it is simply already used for something.

Comment: I mean to say that by using it, we can't use the built-in `len` method. What do you mean by reserved words in python?

Comment: I think they're the keywords like "while" that you cannot use outside of their function, like creating a variable with them. If you try, you'll get a bunch of errors

Answer (score 0):

Pyguy,

- You can break up complex/longer statements into multiple simpler ones for cleaner and comprehensible code.
- Use a debugger(eg: pdb) to debug such errors.

Writing clear code might help in debugging issues quickly.
In your case, I believe this might be the issue:

`Charlist[0[` -> `Charlist[0][`